# WordPress MetaSlider & Advanced Custom Fields integration

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a website in WordPress using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin alongside metaslider, I want the user to be able to select a metaslider from a dropdown list by using a custom field.

I know that you can add a slider in via the WYSIWYG however I want to make a seamless way of doing this, it's probably not as simple as I'd like it to be.

The website consists of projects and will have several sliders all will be appropriately named and I want to make it foolproof for the user.

I've searched online and can't seem to find anyone else who has wanted/tried to to this.

Ask an questions you have if i haven't been clear!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's okay, I figured out how to do it!

You can select a field type of "post object" then add a "post type" of Meta Slider then the user has a dropdown box where they can select which slider they want to display on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Metaslider shortcode id in ACF:

```
$slider_object['value']->ID
```

Try:

```
<?php $slider = get_field_object('slider_item'); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="'.$slider['value']->ID.'"]'); ?>
```